# Populate Select Options Folder with xml files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

This is my HTML code for the select ID:

```
<select class="dropdown-toggle" id="combo"></select>
```

I have this HTML file and I need to populate the options with XML files that I have on a root folder named xml.  I have JQuery imported in the header.  I have tried lots of examples but I can not get it to work.  The XML files are in /XML folder.

Thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
  $.ajax({
  url: '/xml',
  success: function(d){
    $.each(d.split(/[\r\n]+/),function(i,e){


      $('<option>',{ value: e }).text(e),'</option>'.appendTo('#combo');
       });
      }
  });
</script>
```

I tried this code but it is not working...

Comment: need to explain what the `split` is supposed to be for. If you are returning valid xml doc( must be valid for parsing) , there is no need for the `split`. ALso appears you are trying to access a directory and expect numerous files returned... can't do that

Comment: I just need to populate the select with all the xml files in the folder /xml

Comment: imagine i had in the /xml (folder) these:
1.xml
2.xml
abc.xml

in the combobox i need to appear 

1
2
abc

Comment: You can't access a directory only with AJAX. You will need server code to read the file names and return them and point your ajax at that URL that will provide the data

Comment: Can you give me some code so i can try to understand that please?

Comment: what language is server running? Look in docs for that language how to read file names in a directory

Comment: I dont understand that much of this i have been googling and asking around the web for a solution with jquery... but is there otherway to do this?

Comment: not with javascript unless you make your own list in an array, or create html yourself. You are asking to do something that is a very basic server security issue

Comment: but my grade in this could better if i could dinamicly check in the folder the files and parse them to options in the select thats why im trying to do this

Comment: has to be done with server code using language runnng on server. jQuery is javascript and runs in browser only. Will be very simple code and not hard to find it. Create an array on server and send it using json to ajax

Comment: but im testing this in my server where i put my works online but i have to deliver on the university server and upload it there, and i have no information about that... what if i used php could it be done?

Comment: We have no way of knowing what server-side language(s) will run on your university server.

Comment: sure .. use `glob()` in php, then when get access to other server info convert to their language if it's not php

Comment: @charlietfl - Wow. Never heard of `glob` before. Sure is useful. Please check out my answer below, and let me know if I used `glob` correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @JosephSilber `glob()` super easy to build a quick array... to be honest my php is pretty rusty will trust you on it

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you'll have to use some server-side code to generate the list.

---

Here's an example in PHP:

```php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$folder = opendir('path/to/xml');
$list = array();

while ( $file_name = readdir( $folder ) ) {
    // Only get the XML files
    if ( pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) !== 'xml' ) continue;

    $list[] = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}

closedir( $folder );

echo json_encode( $list );
```

---

Or, as pointed out by @charlietfl in the comments above, you could use [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php):

```php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$list = array();

foreach(glob('path/to/xml/*.xml') as $file_name) {  
    $list[] = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}

echo json_encode( $list );
```

---

Once you have that script set up on your server, you can then loop over the array in your JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/list_xml_files.php',
    success: function (data) {

        var $select = $('#combo');

        $.each(data, function(i, v) {
            $('<option>', {
                value: v,
                text: v
            }).appendTo( $select );
        });
    }
});
```

You can further optimize this by having all `append`s done at once, but that's a discussion for another day...